# Obtain the integers already randomly generated into matrices

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, logic

I'm writing a program to do addition, subtraction, division and multiplication among matrices. The program is randomly generating various numbers and placing them into the 2 dimensional arrays (Matrix1 and Matrix2). I have that part down and now I am wanting to add the addiction logic to the currently populated matrices **but i can not figure out how to ** obtain the numbers that were randomly generated in the loop - outside of the loop; to manipulate them.

I am sure this is an easy logical understanding but trying to access my matrix1/matrix2 [i] [j] outside of the loop is not working.

Here is my source code:

---

```
package matrix;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int par1, par2;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter the desired size of the first parameter of the matrix: ");
    par1 = inputReader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the desired size of the second parameter of the matrix: ");
    par2 = inputReader.nextInt();

    int[][] matrix1 = new int[par1][par2];
    int[][] matrix2 = new int[par1][par2];

    System.out.println("Size of parameter 1 is: "+ "["+par1 + "]");
    System.out.println("Size of parameter 2 is: "+ "["+par2 + "]");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Matrix 1: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < par1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < par2; j++) {
            matrix1[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
             System.out.print(matrix1[i][j] + " ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Matrix 2: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < par1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < par2; j++) {
            matrix2[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
             System.out.print(matrix2[i][j] + " ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }

    System.out.println("The addition of the two matrices are: ");
       System.out.println(matrix2[i][j]); <---THIS IS WHAT WILL NOT WORK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i and j are iterators.  In other words, their only function is to iterate over an array.  You can use them within a loop to index into an array but other then that they live in the loop.  After you iterators populate the array they should still hold the numbers, so, just use.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix2));
```

Comment: Does this allow me to manipulate the certain position in the 2D arrays? Or does this simply show what is in them?

Comment: @colt no  its not going to allow you to manipulate anything within the array.  That's what loops are used for.

Comment: additionally, what your are trying to do requries functions (methods) for adding, subtracting etc.  Unless you are doing this for your own knowledge you should have a look at guava, which will greatly simplify the process or can provide inspiration for creating your own methods.

Comment: I understand. Are you meaning already built methods/libraries in java? Because i'm mostly doing this program for fun and was trying to figure out how to hard code it all :). So if im unable to manipulate them do i build a loop inside of my current loop? That may work right? After printing out the current randomly gen'd matrices just build another loop after that one that will add/sub/man/and div :3? that's my thoughts. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @colt  Yep, but don't just build a loop.  Build a method that takes two MD arrays as a parameters and then put your loops inside of that method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, nice replies to comments and explenations!

Answer (score 0):

Given where you declare `i` and `j`, their scope is confined to their respective `for` loops. Therefore you cannot use them outside of these loops. Hence your problematic line of code will not compile.